# Initialize generic parameters in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics

I want to create object of generic property with default initializer. I know this is possible in swift by adding an init method in MyProtocol. Is there any way I can achieve this functionality in objective c

Interface

```
@interface CustomClass<__covariant T:id<MyProtocol>> : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) T result;

-(void) update;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "CustomClass.h"

@implementation CustomClass

-(void) update
{
    //self.result = initialize result here

    [self.result myMethod];
 }

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is late binding and dynamic typing. Neither you need templates (ooops, they call it generics) nor the compiler bind to it. Simply use `id`.

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) id result;
-(void) update;
@end

-(void) update
{
  //self.result = initialize result here
  [self.result myMethod];
}
```

If you want to have a constraint on the type for whatever reason, simply use the protocol:

```
@protocol CustomProtocol
- (void)myMethod;
@end 

@interface CustomClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) id<MyProtocol> result;
-(void) update;
@end

-(void) update
{
  //self.result = initialize result here
  [self.result myMethod];
}
```

After discussion the subject in the comments:

If you want to instantiate a generic type, you do not do this at compile time, but simply pass the type to the initializer at runtime.

Instead of …:

```
var concrete = CustomClass<Concrete>()
```

… you write:

```
CustomClass *concrete = [[CustomClass alloc] initForType:[Concrete class]];
```

Personally I prefer new allocators, but this is another discussion. You can pass the types name as string, too. Personally I do not like that, too. :-)

The initializer looks like this:

```
- (instancetype)initForType:(Class)type
{
  if( (self = [super init] )
  {
    self.result = [type new];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: ? I really cannot know, what you want to assign. You should assign an instance, not a type. Simply use the setter to put a value there. Should `result`be private and initialized, when `CustomClass` is initialized?

Comment: I want to initialize result when CustomClass is initialized. I know I can initialize it and pass it to CustomClass. I want to know if I can do initialization of result in CustomClass

Comment: Okay, and you do not know how to pass the type to the initializer, which would be done in Swift by instantiating the template? You simply pass it at runtime. Added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Lightweight generics in Objective-C are a purely compile-time construct to aid in type checking. They are erased after type-checking and do not exist in the compiled code. There is no `T` at runtime. You cannot write any code that needs to know what `T` is.